# convert a string in to time format in c

Tags: c, time, strftime

suppose I have a string "2011-08-21 21:48:45 +1200",and another one with the same format,
I want to compare these 2 strings to find out which one is the early one or later one, 
is there a easy way to convert a string to time format rather than compare them by characters? 
Thanks

Comment: Pro tip: strptime is in the see also section of the strftime man page.

Comment: what you have tried Show us your work . before you ask something got it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [getdate](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getdate.html) or [strptime()](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strptime.3.asp).

Comment: how do you compare struct tm*?