# Convert from string to long time on C language

Tags: c

We normally convert long time to string of date and time using mktm() or mktime(). Is there anyway we can do the reverse? I want to convert string of date and time to long time. But I could not find any from the internet. For your info, long time means number of seconds from 01/01/1980 00:00:00.

For example, if long time 1045872000 convert to string time using mktm() or mktime() we can get 21/02/2013 00:00:00. Is there any function for reverse? Convert 21/02/2013 00:00:00 to 1045872000.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524543/convert-a-string-in-to-time-format-in-c is this what you are looking for... basically getdate() function reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getdate.html.

Comment: Aren't getdate() is the same function as mktm() or mktime()?

Answer (score 1):

You have [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) but I dont think it is a standard.

> convert a string representation of time to a time tm structure

Answer (score 0):

Strftime  function is convert the Normaltime to Epoch time

```
    #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    int
   main(void)
   {
       struct tm tm;
       char buf[255];

       strptime("2001-11-13 18:31:01", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
       strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s", &tm);
       puts(buf);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

This time 2001-11-13 18:31:01 Epoch time is 1005570061

(or)

system function using convert the epoch time.

```
     system("date -d 'Mon Feb 25 18:05:57 IST 2013' +'%s'");
```

Comment: This function is convert time  to epoch time

Comment: Why do u use strptime first? My compiler don't have this function. It only has strftime.

Comment: I think the strptime is change the string format  to time and stored into the &tm struct .it get and change the string time to separate date and time using access specifiers like %Y .

Comment: The strftime change the time using %s convert time to  epoch time and stored to buffer

Comment: If you use time.h header file

Comment: nope. My compiler don't have strptime in time.h file. Is there any other way to convert time to epoch time?